# Jquery listen to when value changes and alert?

Tags: jquery

I have a div which gets updated by ajax.

Im trying to use jquery to alert when the value of the div gets updated.

I use the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {     

 $('.Current-field').bind('autorefresh.incremental', function() {
  alert($('.Current-field')).val();
 });

 $('.Current-field').trigger('autorefresh.incremental');
});
```

This alerts when the value gets changed as it is supposed to, but the value comes back as [object object]

How do I get the actual value of the updated content, the html is

```
 <span class="field-content Current-field">new content</span>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `text()` or `html()` for div instead of `val()`, you also have wrong closed alert parenthesis.

```
alert($('.Current-field').text());
```

If you have more then one elements with class then you migth need

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Your code would be.

```
$('.Current-field').bind('autorefresh.incremental', function() {
     alert(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a wrapping paren in you `alert` invocation:

```
// this is alerting the jQuery object that is selecting .Current-field
alert($('.Current-field')).val();
// this will alert the returned value of $.val()
alert($('.Current-field').val());
```

Also, I would highly suggest using `console.log` instead of alert. Once you start having multiple alerts on a a page things get *very* messy.